# SQL Select from 1 table, get min max from another table with multiple rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables I wish to 'join' as efficiently as possible.

1st Table has a product code, I need all columns from this one.

2nd Contains the same paorduct code, with multiple rows per product code.

I need to get the min and max of the 2nd tables rows where the product codes match that of the first table.

The below is what I have so far, it's ugly, probably very incorrect and slow. The 2nd table is the issue as this has 750k rows!

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductDescriptions]
(
    @site INT = 0,
    @langid INT = 0
)
AS

select p.* ,
stuff((select ',' + cast(FilterValueID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Filter_Mapping c where c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND c.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as FilterIDs,
stuff((select ',' + cast(BrandID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Brand_Mapping d where d.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND d.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as BrandIDs,
stuff((select '|' + cast(Name as nvarchar(max))from Brands e where e.ID IN (SELECT BrandID FROM Product_Brand_Mapping f WHERE f.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND f.ApplicationID = @site)  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as BrandNames,
stuff((select ',' + cast(DepartmentID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Department_Mapping e where e.ProductCode = p.ProductCode and e.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as DepartmentIDs,
(select MAX(pr.Sell) from Products pr where pr.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND pr.ApplicationID = @site) as SellTo, 
(select MAX(pr.WholeSale) from Products pr where pr.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND pr.ApplicationID = @site) as WasTo
from ProductDescription p WHERE p.ApplicationID = @site AND p.LanguageID = @langid
```

Comment: You said you had only two tables, yet I see references to see several tables within the SELECT list...product_brand_mapping, brands, product_filter_mapping, etc. Can you advise any details on these? These top-level selects can seriously impair performance.

Comment: I believe the performance killer is in the STUFF's/Selects. I'm just not quite clever enough to envision the end result of them; could you provide a sample row of the current output?

Comment: I was also noticing that your final FROM is "ProductDecription p, Products pr", but the WHERE clause doesn't include anything to filter against "pr"....do you not need to add a condition there? And is there a reason you're using the list-style join rather than an explicit "JOIN"?

Comment: ID ProductCode Name Description MetaTitle MetaDescription MetaKeywords Content1 Content2 Content3 Content4 URL LanguageID TemplateID HideInGoogleShopping ApplicationID H1 AltText MaxBasketQty MinStockQty Published ViewCount SoldCount OriginalID Deleted DateAvailable DateAdded SizeGuideID FilterIDs BrandIDs BrandNames DepartmentIDs DisplayOrders SellFrom SellTo WasFrom WasTo
45448 8393 TED GD14 MORAR DS in BLK NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 9 NULL 0 4 NULL NULL 3 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 9,8,11,10 1324 Jiggler Lord Berlue 97 NULL 139.00 139.00 139.00 139.00

Comment: What I need to achieve is the following:

All products from ProductDescriptions WITH

The mappings form various tables in a comma seperated sting in 1 column each, so it gets all the rows from Product_Department_Mapping for instance, and gives me back 1 column of csv string of all of the department ids

AND

The Max Values of the various columns from Products Table where Products.ProductCode = ProductDescription.ProductCode (will return multiple rows in products)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductDescriptions3]
(
    @site INT = 0,
    @langid INT = 0
)
AS

select p.*,
stuff((select ',' + cast(FilterValueID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Filter_Mapping c where c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND c.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as FilterIDs,
stuff((select ',' + cast(BrandID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Brand_Mapping d where d.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND d.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as BrandIDs,
stuff((select '|' + cast(Name as nvarchar(max))from Brands e where e.ID IN (SELECT BrandID FROM Product_Brand_Mapping f WHERE f.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND f.ApplicationID = @site)  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as BrandNames,
stuff((select ',' + cast(DepartmentID as nvarchar(max))from Product_Department_Mapping e where e.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND e.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as DepartmentIDs,
stuff((select ',' + cast(DepartmentID as nvarchar(max)) + '|' + cast(DisplayOrder as nvarchar(max)) from Product_Department_DisplayOrder g where g.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND g.ApplicationID = @site for xml path('')),1,1,'') as DisplayOrders,
X.SellFrom,
X.SellTo,
X.WasFrom,
X.WasTo
FROM ProductDescription p
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT 
    MIN(pr.Sell) as SellFrom,
    MAX(pr.Sell) as SellTo, 
    MIN(pr.Wholesale) as WasFrom, 
    MAX(pr.WholeSale) as WasTo
  FROM Products pr
  WHERE where pr.ProductCode = p.ProductCode AND pr.ApplicationID = @site
  ) X
WHERE p.ApplicationID = @site AND p.LanguageID = @langid
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the above, it works well, however it's still slow.

I need to get multiple tables into one. Product_Department_Mapping gets me the department id's into a column, same goes for filterid, brand names and displayorders.

I use this in my asp.net application where this table is cached and used as a master table.

Are there any quicker ways than STUFF?

Comment: Don't think its the STUFF's per se that slow things down, its just all the secondary selects needed to generate all those CSV lists...

Comment: Yeh you're right, the STUFFs don't slow it down much at all. The OUTER APPLY is taking a very long time. Are there any alternatives, can I get all rows from products where products.productcode = p.productcode into a table in memory and query that for the min/max values?

Also the below code is saying it needs all of the group by's added.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: I don't think `OUTER APPLY` is necessary, an `INNER JOIN` on a subquery grouped by `Products.ProductID` and the same aggregates would work and perform much better than using `APPLY`

Comment: Above is the fastest i've been able to get, is there any way it can be optimised even more?

Comment: @Dave How many rows are in the first table? That determines the suitability of the OUTER APPLY

Comment: BTW, what's the time difference between the query without the outer apply and the last 4 select statement, and with? Also, I've updated the OUTER APPLY to include the @site filter

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a suggestion that's a bit out of the box, so take it FWIW.

I think I would recommend this query be broken down into two parts. I believe if you separated out the portion that calculates your MIN and MAX values alone, just by ProductCode (if I've inferred that correctly), you'd see a marked improvement in performance. The drag comes along with the "Selects in the Selects," eg select a,b,c,(select ...)

I (finally) realized you're using those selects to obtain aggregate/comma-delimited lists of departments/brands/etc, and it occurs to me that if only that portion of the query were (as an example) performed as a subselect or reposed in a view (eg product_detail_info_view), it *might* mitigate the performance hit they encounter. The idea would be for the "nested" Selects to only be performed in one pass. Doing this would allow you to express the query as something more like:

```
select  a.*,ps.SellFrom,ps.SellTo,ps.WasFrom,ps.WasTo
  from  product_detail_info_view a
  join  (select pr.productcode, min(pr.sell) as SellFrom, max(pr.Sell) as SellTo,
                min(pr.WholeSale) as WasFrom, max(pr.WholeSale) as WasTo
           group by pr.productcode) as ps
    on  a.productcode=ps.productcode  -- Or should this be a.productID=ps.productID? Not sure
where a.ApplicationID = @site
  and a.LanguageId = @langid
```

Now, I fully realize that the details of this are not complete, eg not entirely certain about the join fields, but the idea is there. I've often found that the best way to streamline a query is to see if I can break it into chunks, then "reassemble' it into more efficient pieces. I hope that makes some sense.